# Flattening mutliple Rows into a single row based on identifier

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to get a result set (and eventually create a view) that will combine rows based on an identifier. Below is an example of what I have, and what I'm trying to achieve:

Existing Data

```
    /* +----+------+---------+------+-------------------+-------------------+ */
    /* | ID | GUID |  Name   | Age  |      Address      | Entry_Create_Date | */
    /* +----+------+---------+------+-------------------+-------------------+ */
    /* |  1 |  123 | Bob     | 42   | NULL              | 1/2/2018          | */
    /* |  1 |  245 | Bob     | 41   | 123 Muffin Lane   | 1/1/2018          | */
    /* |  1 |  356 | Bob     | NULL | NULL              | 1/3/2018          | */
    /* |  2 |  456 | Charles | 21   | 235 Sherbert Lane | 1/3/2018          | */
    /* +----+------+---------+------+-------------------+-------------------+ */
```

Desired output:

```
    /* +----+---------+-----+-------------------+ */
    /* | ID |  Name   | Age |      Address      | */
    /* +----+---------+-----+-------------------+ */
    /* |  1 | Bob     |  42 | 123 Muffin Lane   | */
    /* |  2 | Charles |  21 | 235 Sherbert Lane | */
    /* +----+---------+-----+-------------------+ */
```

Results use the Entry_Create_Date to determine the latest record. Once that row is found, it uses that as the basis. If the values are NULL, it uses the values of the other rows with the same ID value to get the values from them. Precedence of column value is determined by the date it was created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is complicated.  You seem to want the most recent value from each field.  How about . . .

```
select distinct id, name,
       first_value(age) over (partition by id order by case when age is not null then 1 else 2 end, Entry_Create_Date desc) as age,
       first_value(Address) over (partition by id order by case when Address is not null then 1 else 2 end, Entry_Create_Date desc) as Address
from t;
```

Comment: This is great. I'd never heard of [FIRST_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) before. Learn something new every day!

Comment: This is interesting. I've not seen this before. I will try it out and let you know how it works out :)

Comment: 2 years later on my response here. This absolutely did work out for us and plays a critical role in our design. I will warn any future readers that using this method can introduce performance impacts if the subset of data you're querying against is large. So please keep that in mind when using this.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data suggests me to do aggregation (`NOT EXACTLY`) :

```
SELECT id, Name, MAX(Age), MAX(Address)
FROM table t
WHERE Age IS NOT NULL OR Address IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id, Name;
```